# Neo4j Browser Crash grey screen

Tags: neo4j

```
MATCH (a:Doss)
MATCH (b:Doss)
WHERE a.Num=b.Num
return a,b
```

it takes long time and then no results, just the browser being crashed with grey screen.
NB:in this database i got 6M nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an index on :Doss(Num) or this won't be able to finish in a reasonable amount of time.

The key is that most Cypher operations execute per row. So the second MATCH is being executed per each result from the first MATCH.

If you don't have an index, then this will likely be doing a NodeByLabelScan for `a`, and then another NodeByLabelScan **per `a` node** and filtering to find matches for `b`.

Basically, you will be performing a total of 6M + 1 label scans, and filtering across 6M * 6M rows, and that's just not a good idea.

If you add the index, then you will be doing only one NodeByLabelScan, and then 6M index seeks to find, per row, all `b` nodes with the same num as `a`.

You should be able to run an EXPLAIN on the query to confirm how the planner wants to execute this.

Comment: When i try to create an index for :Doss(Num) it says that an index already exists